# Modbus connection over TCP and Serial port

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, tcp, serial-port

I want to improve my code. In this code I don't like my constructor, but without it I keep getting an error while trying to connect `NullPointerException`.

```
package soft;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusException;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusIOException;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusSlaveException;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusSerialTransaction;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadCoilsRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadCoilsResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputRegistersResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadMultipleRegistersRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadMultipleRegistersResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.WriteMultipleRegistersRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.WriteMultipleRegistersResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.WriteSingleRegisterRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.WriteSingleRegisterResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.SerialConnection;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.TCPMasterConnection;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.Register;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleRegister;
import net.wimpi.modbus.util.SerialParameters;

/**
 * This class realizes modbus protocol
 * communication over TCP and Serial Port and most of modbus functions.
 *
 * @author Tomas Ausvicas
 */

public class BackEnd {

    /** The tcp con. */
    TCPMasterConnection tcpCon;

    /** The serial con. */
    SerialConnection serialCon;

    /** The transaction tcp. */
    ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP;

    /** The transaction serial. */
    ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial;

    /** The params. */
    SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();

    /** The rcreq. */
    ReadCoilsRequest rcreq = new ReadCoilsRequest();

    /** The rcres. */
    ReadCoilsResponse rcres = new ReadCoilsResponse();

    /** The rireq. */
    ReadInputRegistersRequest rireq = new ReadInputRegistersRequest();

    /** The rires. */
    ReadInputRegistersResponse rires = new ReadInputRegistersResponse();

    /** The ridreq. */
    ReadInputDiscretesRequest ridreq = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest();

    /** The ridres. */
    ReadInputDiscretesResponse ridres = new ReadInputDiscretesResponse();

    /** The write_sreq. */
    WriteSingleRegisterRequest write_sreq = new WriteSingleRegisterRequest();

    /** The write_sres. */
    WriteSingleRegisterResponse write_sres = new WriteSingleRegisterResponse();

    /** The read_mreq. */
    ReadMultipleRegistersRequest read_mreq = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest();

    /** The read_mres. */
    ReadMultipleRegistersResponse read_mres = new `ReadMultipleRegistersResponse();`

    /** The write_mreq. */
    WriteMultipleRegistersRequest write_mreq = new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest();

    /** The write_mres. */
    WriteMultipleRegistersResponse write_mres = new WriteMultipleRegistersResponse();

    /** The register. */
    SimpleRegister regL, regH, register;

    /** The registers. */
    Register[] registers;

    /** The int16 result. */
    private int[] int16Result;

    /** The int32 result. */
    private int[] int32Result;

    /** The float result. */
    private float[] floatResult;

    /** The round float result. */
    private float[] roundFloatResult;

    /** The string16 result. */
    private String[] string16Result;

    /** The string32 result. */
    private String[] string32Result;

    /** The string float result. */
    private String[] stringFloatResult;

    /** The round string float result. */
    private String[] roundStringFloatResult;

    /** The string coil result. */
    private String[] stringCoilResult;

    /** The boolean coil result. */
    private boolean[] booleanCoilResult;

    /** The string discrete input result. */
    private String[] stringDiscreteInputResult;

    /** The boolean discrete input result. */
    private boolean[] booleanDiscreteInputResult;

    /** The string read bit result. */
    private String[] stringReadBitResult;

    /** The boolean read bit result. */
    private boolean[] booleanReadBitResult;

    /** The int analog input registers result. */
    private int[] intAnalogInputRegistersResult;

    /** The string analog input registers result. */
    private String[] stringAnalogInputRegistersResult;

    /** The to string. */
    private String[] toString;

    /**
     * Default constructor with TCP and Serial Port objects created.
     */
    public BackEnd() {

    try {
        tcpCon = new TCPMasterConnection(InetAddress.getByName(""));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknow Host");
    }
    params = new SerialParameters();
    serialCon = new SerialConnection(params);
    }

    /**
     * Connect over TCP.
     *
     * @param ipAddress the ip address
     * @param port the port
     */
    public void connectTCP(String ipAddress, int port) {

        try {
            tcpCon = new TCPMasterConnection(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Įveskite IP adresą", "Invalid input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        tcpCon.setPort(port);
        try {
            tcpCon.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nepavyko prisijungti prie serverio. [TCP/IP]", "Connection error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        transactionTCP = new ModbusTCPTransaction(tcpCon);

    }

    /**
     * Set parameters for serial com.
     *
     * @param portName the port name
     * @param baudRate the baud rate
     * @param dataBits the data bits
     * @param stopBits the stop bits
     * @param parity the parity
     * @param encoding the encoding
     * @param echo the echo
     */
    public void connectSerial(String portName, int baudRate, int dataBits, int stopBits, String parity, String encoding,
            boolean echo) {

        SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();

        params.setPortName(portName);
        params.setDatabits(dataBits);
        params.setParity(parity);
        params.setStopbits(stopBits);
        params.setEncoding(encoding);
        params.setEcho(echo);
        params.setBaudRate(baudRate);

        serialCon = new SerialConnection(params);

        try {
            serialCon.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nepavyko prisijungti prie serverio. [Serial port]", "Connection error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        transactionSerial = new ModbusSerialTransaction(serialCon);
    }

    /**
     * Close TCP connection.
     */
    public void closeTCP() {
        tcpCon.close();
    }

    /**
     * Close Serial connection.
     */
    public void closeSerial() {
        serialCon.close();
    }

    /**
     * Check if TCP connected.
     *
     * @return boolean value
     */
    public boolean isConnectedTCP() {
        return tcpCon.isConnected();

    }

    /**
     * Check if Serial connected.
     *
     * @return boolean value
     */
    public boolean isOpenSerial() {
        return serialCon.isOpen();
    }

    /**
     * Writes single 16bit number to register (16 bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWrite the data to write
     */
    public void WriteSingle_16Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int dataToWrite) {

        SimpleRegister reg = new SimpleRegister(dataToWrite);

        write_sreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_sreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_sreq.setRegister(reg);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_sreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception write 16");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception write 16");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception write 16");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes double 16bit number to register (32 bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWrite the data to write
     */
    public void WriteSingle_32Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int dataToWrite) {

        int count = 2;

        int HIGH = dataToWrite >> 16;
        int LOW = dataToWrite & 0xFFFF;

        regH = new SimpleRegister(HIGH);
        regL = new SimpleRegister(LOW);

        registers = new Register[count];

        for (int i = 0, a = 1; i < registers.length; i += 2, a += 2) {
            registers[i] = regL;
            registers[a] = regH;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception write 32");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception write 32");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception write 32");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes double 16bit number to register (32bit float).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWriteF the data to write f
     */
    public void WriteSingle_Float(int unitID, int startAddress, float dataToWriteF) {

        int count = 2;

        int number = Float.floatToIntBits(dataToWriteF);
        int HIGH = number >> 16;
        int LOW = number & 0xFFFF;

        regH = new SimpleRegister(HIGH);
        regL = new SimpleRegister(LOW);

        registers = new Register[count];

        for (int i = 1, a = 0; i < registers.length; i += 2, a += 2) {
            registers[i] = regL;
            registers[a] = regH;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception write float");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception write float");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception write float");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes multiple 16bit numbers to chosen registers (16bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWrite the data to write
     * @param count the count
     */
    public void WriteMultiple_16Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int dataToWrite, int count) {

        register = new SimpleRegister(dataToWrite);
        registers = new Register[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < registers.length; i++) {
            registers[i] = register;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mwrite 16");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mwrite 16");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mwrite 16");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes multiple double 16bit numbers to chosen registers (32bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWrite the data to write
     * @param count the count
     */
    public void WriteMultiple_32Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int dataToWrite, int count) {

        int HIGH = dataToWrite >> 16;
        int LOW = dataToWrite & 0xFFFF;

        regH = new SimpleRegister(HIGH);
        regL = new SimpleRegister(LOW);

        registers = new Register[count * 2];

        for (int i = 0, a = 1; i < registers.length; i += 2, a += 2) {
            registers[i] = regL;
            registers[a] = regH;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mwrite 32");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mwrite 32");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mwrite 32");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes multiple double 16bit numbers to chosen registers (32bit float).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param dataToWriteF the data to write f
     * @param count the count
     */
    public void WriteMultiple_Float(int unitID, int startAddress, float dataToWriteF, int count) {

        int number = Float.floatToIntBits(dataToWriteF);
        int HIGH = number >> 16;
        int LOW = number & 0xFFFF;

        regH = new SimpleRegister(HIGH);
        regL = new SimpleRegister(LOW);

        registers = new Register[count * 2];

        for (int i = 1, a = 0; i < registers.length; i += 2, a += 2) {
            registers[i] = regL;
            registers[a] = regH;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mwrite float");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mwrite float");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mwrite float");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple 16bit numbers from chosen registers (16bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return multiple registers
     */
    public BackEnd ReadMultiple_16Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.int16Result = new int[count];
        this.string16Result = new String[count];

        read_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        read_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        read_mreq.setWordCount(count);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, read_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mread 16");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mread 16");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mread 16");
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < read_mres.getWordCount(); n++) {
            int16Result[n] = read_mres.getRegisterValue(n);
            string16Result[n] = String.valueOf(int16Result[n]);

        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple double 16bit numbers from chosen registers (32bit integer).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return multiple registers
     */
    public BackEnd ReadMultiple_32Bit(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.int32Result = new int[count];
        this.string32Result = new String[count];

        int[] z = new int[count * 2];
        int[] y = new int[count * 2];

        int[] h = new int[count];
        int[] l = new int[count];

        read_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        read_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        read_mreq.setWordCount(count * 2);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, read_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mread 32");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mread 32");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mread 32");
        }

        for (int n = 0, i = 1; n < read_mres.getWordCount(); n += 2, i += 2) {
            z[n] = read_mres.getRegisterValue(n);
            y[i] = (read_mres.getRegisterValue(i) << 16);
        }

        for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < l.length; a++, b += 2) {
            l[a] = z[b];
        }

        for (int a = 0, b = 1; a < h.length; a++, b += 2) {
            h[a] = y[b];
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < int32Result.length; n++) {
            int32Result[n] = h[n] | l[n];
            string32Result[n] = String.valueOf(int32Result[n]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple double 16bit numbers from chosen registers (32 bit float).
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return multiple registers
     */
    public BackEnd ReadMultiple_Float(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.floatResult = new float[count];
        this.stringFloatResult = new String[count];
        this.roundFloatResult = new float[count];
        this.roundStringFloatResult = new String[count];

        int[] x = new int[count * 2];
        int[] y = new int[count * 2];

        int[] h = new int[count];
        int[] l = new int[count];

        read_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        read_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        read_mreq.setWordCount(count * 2);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, read_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception mread float");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception mread float");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception mread float");
        }

        for (int n = 1, i = 0; n < read_mres.getWordCount(); n += 2, i += 2) {
            x[n] = read_mres.getRegisterValue(n);
            y[i] = (read_mres.getRegisterValue(i) << 16);
        }

        for (int a = 0, b = 1; a < l.length; a++, b += 2) {
            l[a] = x[b];
        }

        for (int a = 0, b = 0; a < h.length; a++, b += 2) {
            h[a] = y[b];
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < floatResult.length; n++) {
            floatResult[n] = Float.intBitsToFloat(h[n] | l[n]);
            stringFloatResult[n] = String.valueOf(floatResult[n]);
            roundFloatResult[n] = (float) Math.round(floatResult[n] * 100) / 100;
            roundStringFloatResult[n] = Float.toString(roundFloatResult[n]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple coils from chosen registers.
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return coil as boolean or String
     */
    public BackEnd ReadCoilStatus(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.booleanCoilResult = new boolean[count];
        this.stringCoilResult = new String[count];

        rcreq.setReference(startAddress);
        rcreq.setBitCount(count);
        rcreq.setUnitID(unitID);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, rcreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            booleanCoilResult[i] = rcres.getCoilStatus(i);
            stringCoilResult[i] = String.valueOf(booleanCoilResult[i]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple discrete inputs from chosen registers.
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return discrete input as boolean or String
     */
    public BackEnd ReadDiscreteInputStatus(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.booleanDiscreteInputResult = new boolean[count];
        this.stringDiscreteInputResult = new String[count];

        ridreq.setReference(startAddress);
        ridreq.setBitCount(count);
        ridreq.setUnitID(unitID);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, ridreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            booleanDiscreteInputResult[i] = ridres.getDiscreteStatus(i);
            stringDiscreteInputResult[i] = String.valueOf(booleanDiscreteInputResult[i]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Reads multiple analog inputs from chosen registers.
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param count the count
     * @return analog input register value (int or String)
     */
    public BackEnd ReadAnalogInputRegisters(int unitID, int startAddress, int count) {

        this.intAnalogInputRegistersResult = new int[count];
        this.stringAnalogInputRegistersResult = new String[count];

        rireq.setReference(startAddress);
        rireq.setWordCount(count);
        rireq.setUnitID(unitID);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, rireq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            intAnalogInputRegistersResult[i] = rires.getRegisterValue(i);
            stringAnalogInputRegistersResult[i] = String.valueOf(intAnalogInputRegistersResult[i]);
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Read bit from a register.
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param position            D15..D0
     * @param count the count
     * @return bit as boolean or String
     */
    public BackEnd ReadBit(int unitID, int startAddress, int position, int count) {

        this.stringReadBitResult = new String[count];
        this.booleanReadBitResult = new boolean[count];
        this.toString = new String[count];

        // String[] toString = new String[count];

        read_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        read_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        read_mreq.setWordCount(count);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, read_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception read bit");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception read bit");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception read bit");
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < read_mres.getWordCount(); n++) {

            try {
                toString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000 | read_mres.getRegisterValue(n)).substring(1);

                if (toString[n].charAt(15 - position) == '0') {
                    booleanReadBitResult[n] = false;
                    stringReadBitResult[n] = String.valueOf(false);
                } else if (toString[n].charAt(15 - position) == '1') {
                    booleanReadBitResult[n] = true;
                    stringReadBitResult[n] = String.valueOf(true);
                }
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Write bit to a register.
     *
     * @param unitID the unit id
     * @param startAddress the start address
     * @param position            D15..D0
     * @param bitas            true=0, false=1
     * @param count the count
     */
    public void WriteBit(int unitID, int startAddress, int position, boolean bitas, int count) {

        String value = "";

        if (bitas == true) {
            value = "1";
        } else if (bitas == false) {
            value = "0";
        }

        int[] x = new int[count];
        String[] toString = new String[count];
        String[] Format16Bit = new String[count];

        read_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);
        read_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        read_mreq.setWordCount(count);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, read_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception Readwrite bit");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception Readwrite bit");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception Readwrite bit");
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < read_mres.getWordCount(); n++) {
            toString[n] = Integer.toBinaryString(0x10000 | read_mres.getRegisterValue(n)).substring(1);
        }

        registers = new Register[count];

        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++) {
            Format16Bit[n] = toString[n].substring(0, 15 - position) + value + toString[n].substring(15 - position + 1);
            x[n] = Integer.parseInt(Format16Bit[n], 2);
            register = new SimpleRegister(x[n]);
            registers[n] = register;
        }

        write_mreq.setReference(startAddress);
        write_mreq.setRegisters(registers);
        write_mreq.setUnitID(unitID);

        try {
            transaction(transactionTCP, transactionSerial, write_mreq);
        } catch (ModbusIOException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus IO Exception Write bit");
        } catch (ModbusSlaveException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Slave Exception Write bit");
        } catch (ModbusException e) {
            System.out.println("Modbus Exception Write bit");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overloading method for transaction over modbus protocol.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param write_mreq the write_mreq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            WriteMultipleRegistersRequest write_mreq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(write_mreq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] write_mreq error");
        }

        try {
            transactionSerial.setRequest(write_mreq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] write_mreq error");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Overloading method.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param write_sreq the write_sreq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            WriteSingleRegisterRequest write_sreq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(write_sreq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] write_sreq error");
        }

        try {
            transactionSerial.setRequest(write_sreq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] write_sreq error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overloading method.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param read_mreq the read_mreq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            ReadMultipleRegistersRequest read_mreq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(read_mreq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            read_mres = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] read_mreq error");
        }

        try {

            transactionSerial.setRequest(read_mreq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            read_mres = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] read_mreq error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overloading method.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param rcreq the rcreq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            ReadCoilsRequest rcreq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(rcreq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            rcres = (ReadCoilsResponse) transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] rcreq error");
        }

        try {
            transactionSerial.setRequest(rcreq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            rcres = (ReadCoilsResponse) transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] rcreq error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overloading method.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param rireq the rireq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            ReadInputRegistersRequest rireq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(rireq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            rires = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] rireq error");
        }

        try {
            transactionSerial.setRequest(rireq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            rires = (ReadInputRegistersResponse) transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] rireq error");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Overloading method.
     *
     * @param transactionTCP the transaction tcp
     * @param transactionSerial the transaction serial
     * @param ridreq the ridreq
     * @throws ModbusIOException the modbus io exception
     * @throws ModbusSlaveException the modbus slave exception
     * @throws ModbusException the modbus exception
     */

    public void transaction(ModbusTCPTransaction transactionTCP, ModbusSerialTransaction transactionSerial,
            ReadInputDiscretesRequest ridreq) throws ModbusIOException, ModbusSlaveException, ModbusException {

        try {
            transactionTCP.setRequest(ridreq);
            transactionTCP.execute();
            ridres = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) transactionTCP.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[TCP] ridreq error");
        }

        try {
            transactionSerial.setRequest(ridreq);
            transactionSerial.execute();
            ridres = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) transactionSerial.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[Serial] ridreq error");
        }
    }
        /**
     * Gets the 16 bit int.
     *
     * @return 16bit numbers as int array
     */
    public int[] get16BitInt() {
        return int16Result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 32 bit int.
     *
     * @return 32bit numbers as int array
     */
    public int[] get32BitInt() {
        return int32Result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the float.
     *
     * @return 32bit float numbers as float array
     */
    public float[] getFloat() {
        return floatResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the round float.
     *
     * @return 32bit float numbers as rounded float array
     */
    public float[] getRoundFloat() {
        return roundFloatResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 16 bit string.
     *
     * @return 16bit numbers as String array
     */
    public String[] get16BitString() {
        return string16Result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 32 bit string.
     *
     * @return 32bit numbers as String array
     */
    public String[] get32BitString() {
        return string32Result;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the float string.
     *
     * @return 32bit float numbers as String array
     */
    public String[] getFloatString() {
        return stringFloatResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the round float string.
     *
     * @return 32bit float numbers as rounded String array
     */
    public String[] getRoundFloatString() {
        return roundStringFloatResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 16 bit at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 16bit number from int array at index
     */
    public int get16BitAtIndex(int index) {
        return int16Result[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 32 bit at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit number from int array at index
     */
    public int get32BitAtIndex(int index) {
        return int32Result[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the float at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit foat number from float array at index
     */
    public float getFloatAtIndex(int index) {
        return floatResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the round float at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit rounded float number from rounded float array at index
     */
    public float getRoundFloatAtIndex(int index) {
        return roundFloatResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 16 bit string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 16bit rounded float number from rounded String array at index
     */
    public String get16BitStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return string16Result[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the 32 bit string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit number from String array at index
     */
    public String get32BitStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return string32Result[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the float string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit float number from String array at index
     */
    public String getFloatStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return stringFloatResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the round float string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return 32bit rounded float number from rounded String array at index
     */
    public String getRoundFloatStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return roundStringFloatResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the coil boolean at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return coil status from boolean array at index
     */
    public Boolean getCoilBooleanAtIndex(int index) {
        return booleanCoilResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the coil string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return coil status from String array at index
     */
    public String getCoilStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return stringCoilResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the coil boolean.
     *
     * @return coil status from boolean array
     */
    public boolean[] getCoilBoolean() {
        return booleanCoilResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the coil string.
     *
     * @return coil status from String array
     */
    public String[] getCoilString() {
        return stringCoilResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the read bit boolean.
     *
     * @return bit status from boolean array
     */
    public boolean[] getReadBitBoolean() {
        return booleanReadBitResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the read bit boolean at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return bit status from boolean array at index
     */
    public boolean getReadBitBooleanAtIndex(int index) {
        return booleanReadBitResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the read bit string.
     *
     * @return bit status from String array
     */
    public String[] getReadBitString() {
        return stringReadBitResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the read bit string bin.
     *
     * @return String binary format (01010101..)
     */
    public String[] getReadBitStringBin() {

        StringBuilder[] str = new StringBuilder[toString.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            str[i] = new StringBuilder(toString[i]);
            int idx = str[i].length() - 4;

            while (idx > 0) {
                str[i].insert(idx, " ");
                toString[i] = str[i].toString();
                idx = idx - 4;
            }
        }
        return toString;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the read bit string at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return bit status from String array at index
     */
    public String getReadBitStringAtIndex(int index) {
        return stringReadBitResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the boolean discrete input result.
     *
     * @return dicrete input status from boolean array
     */
    public boolean[] getBooleanDiscreteInputResult() {
        return booleanDiscreteInputResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the boolean discrete input result at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return dicrete input status from boolean array at index
     */
    public boolean getBooleanDiscreteInputResultAtIndex(int index) {
        return booleanDiscreteInputResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the string discrete input result.
     *
     * @return dicrete input status from String array
     */
    public String[] getStringDiscreteInputResult() {
        return stringDiscreteInputResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the string discrete input result at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return dicrete input status from String array at index
     */
    public String getStringDiscreteInputResultAtIndex(int index) {
        return stringDiscreteInputResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the int analog input registers result.
     *
     * @return analog input status from int array
     */
    public int[] getIntAnalogInputRegistersResult() {
        return intAnalogInputRegistersResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the int analog input registers result at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return analog input status from int array at index
     */
    public int getIntAnalogInputRegistersResultAtIndex(int index) {
        return intAnalogInputRegistersResult[index];
    }

    /**
     * Gets the string analog input registers result.
     *
     * @return analog input status from String array
     */
    public String[] getStringAnalogInputRegistersResult() {
        return stringAnalogInputRegistersResult;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the string analog input registers result at index.
     *
     * @param index the index
     * @return analog input status from String array at index
     */
    public String getStringAnalogInputRegistersResultAtIndex(int index) {
        return stringAnalogInputRegistersResult[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some more context to your question and explain what your code is dong. See also [checklist to write a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Comment: To be honest, reviewing a 1k3 lines class is too much for me. Have you considered breaking that class into multiple classes for handling the different responsibilities ? (serial, TCP, ModBus, request, response)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `params` and `serialCon` do not get initialized if you leave out the constructor. How about initializing them at their definitions as per a lot of the other variables?

Comment: For `serialCon` you seem to be right, but `params` is definitely initialized. Aside from that, the constructor CANNOT be skipped. So I don't quite know what your point is - should all the variable initialization be done the same way?

Comment: Do I always have to initialize variables at the top like `Example e = new Example();`? Or why can't  write `Example e;` at the top and then in a specific method I initialize`e = new Example();`. For instance, I want to initialize `tcpCon` only then I call `connectTCP` method.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Also, 
If you are using a variable inside one method, then it can be defined inside the method, in fact you do this to `serialCon` already.

Comment: This answer is not attempting to review the code other than a small point, and would be better as a comment on the question, in its current form.

Comment: @Phrancis This answer is trying to make a suggestion rather than seeking clarification, so it should be an answer rather than a comment.